# How to get the objective value in Gurobi at every iteration

Tags: python, gurobi

I have built a model in gurobi python, I am trying to check the rate of convergence and want to know the value of objective function at every iteration. How can I retrieve this information after I solve the problem.

Comment: Define a callback and read the docs how to retrieve the objective within the callback. And i hope you got a good reason to measure this as i don't think many tasks should be approached like that (iteration-improvement vs. iteration-time or different view: achieved objective per x iterations vs. achieved objective per x time).

Comment: Is this an LP (which algorithm)? A MIP?

Comment: It is a LP problem